# The cursor randomly disappears in Eclipse 2019-09 and sometimes stops writing

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, editor

I have a very annoying problem with Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13.0) version: while I'm editing code (often when I copy and paste things or after accepting a code completion suggestion) the cursor (I'm talking about the text cursor: `|`) disappears completely! I cannot see it anymore, so I'm not able to detect on which part of the line I am! This is very annoying. I found a partial fix by installing the extension 'Vrapper': enabling and disabling it makes the cursor appear again.

Another problem I experience every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to ask for code completion suggestions, the cursor stops writing. After doing random things like switching tabs or opening new files the cursor starts to write again, but then the keyboard shortcuts stop working and I have to restart the entire IDE.

This behavior is intolerable, so I was wondering whether somebody else has had the same problem and how they have dealt with it.

The configuration of my system is:
OS: Debian, using i3wm+compton as a window manager on Xserver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One downvote and one vote to close this question, *without giving any reasons*

Comment: Do you have additional plug-ins installed?

Comment: @howlger only Vrapper, but the problem existed even before its installation.

Comment: Which GTK version do you have exactly? Sounds like [Eclipse bug 495220](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495220), but that was fixed quite some time ago.

Comment: @howlger `About -> Installation details -> Configuration` reports these lines: `org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.theme=Adwaita
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.version=3.24.5
org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkitgtk.version=2.24.4` from which I understand that I'm using GTK 3.24.5. Perhaps I should try to switch to GTK2. I'll give it a try and see if it works correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, [GTK2 support has been dropped](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/platform.php#gtk2-removal). Maybe you can try to update GTK3.

Comment: I tried to run `apt install libgtk3-0 libgtk3-bin libgtk3-common`, but it says that they're all updated at the newest version

Comment: Any ideas where the focus is going? Have you tried a different window manager?

Comment: @nitind no, I have not tried any other window managers, but the cursor writes code even when I cannot see it, so I guess that the focus is on the control which displays and edits the code.

Comment: extremely annoying, and still not fixed (eclipse 2021-09)

Answer (score 4):

Dead place, but I'm currently dealing with the same. The weird thing is that it happens on a per-file basis. Eclipse also treats that file as if it was not open, i.e. I can only save it through the 'Save all' method, not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> ('Save') as I usually do. It's hellishly annoying, but **it usually is fixed by reopening the file in question, and editing other files between the closing and reopening of other files.**

If you have a better answer than this that you've found since, please, please post it here. It's annoying as all hell.

Comment: I'm getting this issue when using i3.  If I switch to another workspace and back, the cursor returns.

Comment: @GuyG did you maybe find any solution to this? It happens also to me when using i3.

Comment: @Alex- No, sorry, nothing beyond quickly switching to another workspace and back.  That and moving to more frontend development, thus switching to VS Code.

Comment: This also happens in Awesome.

Comment: still happens (eclipse 2021-06) with awesome (4.3). i made a workaround keybind that sets it minimized for a 1/1000 of a second. i press it everytime this happens

Comment: and also on eclipse 2021-09

Comment: For me, F10-F10 works, or clicking any top menu item with a mouse (i3).

Answer (score 2):

Minimize eclipse and maximize again.
Happened to me on Eclipse 2022-09 (4.25.0).

Comment: switch to another application and come back to eclipse also solves the problem